# ggplot2 conditional colours by if statement

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted the bar graph:
[image]

using this code:

```
qp  <- ggplot(data=RiskData, aes(x=MachineName, y=risk,)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
qp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

What I would like to do is colour each individual bar based on its risk. I.e. red between values of 99 and 100.  Yellow between values of 50 to 98 and green between 0 and 49.  I know how to do it with a normal plot but not in ggplot2.  In a normal plot i would use something along the lines of

```
col = ifelse(......)
```

I have tried this:

```
 qp  <- ggplot(data=RiskData, aes(x=MachineName, y=risk,
                               colour = ifelse(risk>70,"red","green"))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
  qp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

but i get this weird result....

[image]

Then trying with fill instead of colour:

[image]

Thanks

```
A   70
B   10
C   60
D   75
E   60
F   50
G   45
H   60
I   10
J   10
K   50
L   50
M   90
N   20
O   25
P   14
Q   56
R   64
S   24
T   30
U   20
V   97
W   25
X   41
Y   30
Z   10
A1  97
B1  85
C1  70
D1  70
E1  20
F1  100
G1  20
H1  20
I1  80
J1  20
K1  50
```

Comment: One way would be to create a group variable based on the values for risk. You can use `cut` or `ifelse` twice and create a new column. Then, you would assign the column to `colour`.

Comment: Have you tried `fill` instead of `colour`?

Comment: yes... just uploaded the result then... the colours are a little off??

Comment: Would you be able to provide reproducible data?

Comment: I can but i don't see how that would help

Comment: See the other answer for a full description. You do not specify color names when using color as an aesthetic (`aes`). Do something like `fill = ifelse(risk>99,"high",ifelse(risk>50,"medium","low"))))` to define the groups and then add `scale_fill_manual(values=c(high="red",medium="yellow",low="green"), name="Risk Category")` to your plot to set the colors for the groups.

Comment: I can see how the solutions are very similar to the problem but I wouldn't call it a duplicate question though.  If I were looking on the internet for this particular problem I wouldn't think that, that particular question would answer my issue